# Disc quotient that is homeomorphic to the pinched torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, equivalence-relations

I apologize for my previous post. There was a mistake. 
I want to write a quotient of the disc $D^2:={\{z\in\mathbb R^2;\parallel z\parallel \leq 1 }\}$ by an equivalence relation which is homeomorphic to the pinched torus. I have found something a little bit complicated. Some idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way in my opinion is to say that the pinched torus is (homeomorphic to) $D^2/\sim$ where 
$$
x \sim y \Leftrightarrow \text{Either of }\cases{||x|| = ||y|| = 1\\||x|| = 1 \text{ and } y = 0\\ x = 0 \text{ and } ||y|| = 1}
$$
The first condition will collapse $S^1 = \{z \in D^2 \mid ||z|| = 1\}$ to one point, making $D^2$ into the sphere $S^2$, and the two next ones will glue the south pole and north pole of that sphere together to make a pinched torus.

Comment: Very clear answer! Thank you.

Comment: With my notation can i write : $z \sim z' \Leftrightarrow \parallel z  \parallel = \parallel z'  \parallel = 1 $ and $"z_N = z_P"$